# Why did Time Machine have to do a deep event scan?

Tags: macos, time-machine

Time Machine needed to do a deep event scan when backing up to my USB hard drive:

```
11/12/2015 18:03:43.470 com.apple.backupd[1058]: Deep event scan at path:/ reason:contains changes|must scan subdirs|fsevent|file event|renamed|
```

What does this imply happened? What caused it to need to do a deep event scan?

Whatever it is, I'd like to avoid doing it in future...

Comment: This might not be answerable. The code that triggers the scans is not the same from OS X version to version. Are you instead wanting to ask what the scan does? That's a more practical question for the site. The scan is clearly/plainly a verification step to make sure the backup will be viable, but I'm guessing you know that already.

Comment: The deep event scan doesn't check the backup is viable (at least not as such) - it does a full diff between backup and current state, because it's lost track of the journal that it would otherwise use to decide what to back up. I just wonder why it's doing it. What, for example, might `contains changes` mean? But who cares what my own problem is - a more useful question would be what the complete list is, so that all readers may benefit.

Comment: I don't disagree that a list of things is useful - we just aren't a good place for wiki-style lists for a lot of reasons. Ask about this question on [meta] if you're interested in the back story on why "list of X" questions do less well than specific - "how do I X"

Comment: Let me rephrase my question.